# I've heard hog panels have lead in them, should I be worried?

Tags: support

A sales associate told me that the wire used in concrete to hold it together better has lead in it (10 gauge), should I worry about using it in my garden?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One MSDS I saw for rebar mesh shows lead at around 0.07 % of the total material weight.  There are lots of other chemicals in it too.  It's mostly iron.

I guess a good question is "How likely is it for lead to end up in the soil?"

A second question to ask is "If it does get into the soil, how likely is it to end up in my plants?".

It is my opinion that it is unlikely to end up in your soil in any appreciable amount and thus unlikely to end up in your plants.  I have 30 tomato cages made from rebar mesh and it works very well even though it does rust.  Mine are > 10 years old and still are holding up quite well.

The hog/cattle/sheep panels that you can get at Tractor Supply and other places work very well in the garden.  I don't worry about them causing any issues in the garden.  I use them as well.

Comment: Not much info out there on this subject.  Our tap water however has more lead and other stuff in it at higher levels than what they've found in what little research that has been done on WW and soil.  I use well water not tap water and have a greenhouse made over the garden to defray the heavy metals from geoengineering.  I vote for no big deal in the big picture saving your plants from critters.  Couldn't find any studies at all on WW fencing including the solder.  I guess the biggest danger is Zinc being vaporized, nanosized when cutting.  DO NOT breathe this stuff in.

Answer (score 2):

4X4 welded wire mesh for concrete reinforcement is not the same as hog fencing, 4X4...lead is soft.  I have to go research a bit to make sure, but there should be no lead in the rebar or the wire mesh for flatwork concrete.  Now, the welds might have lead involved.  The solder.

Our tap water has more lead than what little lead there is in the welding solder...the stratospheric geo-engineering going on, is spraying more lead, aluminum...heavy metals into our atmosphere to play with weather control and those heavy metals come raining down into our soils and water and makes worrying about leaching of lead from solder points into the soil a bit more insignificant.

Are you putting that welded wire fencing IN the soil?  I would frame it with pt dimensional lumber and not worry.  Beautiful fencing.  I doubt this is the same thing as 4X4 welded wire mesh for concrete.  Please let us know exactly what type of panels you've purchased.  Galvanized?  There are great welded wire panels that are made to powder coat black install in a frame to make fencing.  Not at all 4X4 ww mesh.

Pretty sure that lead is not in the metal, it is in the welding material, if that.

Comment: i'm putting u-posts down for support then the 4x4 mesh vertically to support both my egg plants, tomatoes et al as well as my vines for summer squash, muskmelon, et al, and taking up the lower space with the spinach, kale, swiss chard, et al.